# In Aurelia: How do I bind the output of a webcam to the `srcObject` attribute of a video element?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How do I bind the output of a webcam to the `srcObject` attribute of a video element in [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/)?

I have the following `video` element in my HTML

```
<video id="video" srcObject.bind="cameraStream" if.bind="cameraStream">Video stream not available.</video>
```

In my JavaScript file, I have the following

```
activate() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
        .then((stream) => {
            this.cameraStream = stream
            console.log('this.cameraStream', this.cameraStream)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`An error occurred:`, err)
        })
}
```

The page asks for access to the webcam, and I've logged the value of `this.cameraStream` and I get the output below, but I'm not getting any content in the video object.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

Problem #1: I should have been using the `attached` handler instead of the `activate` handler because the page object may not be loaded in the `activate` handler.

Problem #2: I needed to use the `ref` attribute on the video element to reference the element in JS.

Problem #3: I needed to remove the `if.bind` because the `ref="video"` attribute will not define `this.video` if the element is not present because of `if.bind` evaluating to false.

Here's the final working code.

#### HTML

```
<video id="video" ref="video">Video stream not available.</video>
```

#### JS

```
    attached() {
        let video = this.video

        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
            .then((stream) => {
                video.srcObject = stream
                video.play()
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`An error occurred:`, err)
            })
    }
```